# RHEL 6 on 172.16* IP address: Redirect Internet traffic to an existing web proxy

Tags: proxy, redhat, http, squid

I'd like to configure my RHEL 6 box to redirect Internet traffic through an existing web proxy.  Like how you can set a web browser to use a proxy, except that my box only has command line.

If the answer involves using Squid, can someone give me an example squid.conf file for v.3.1.10 that can redirect traffic to an existing proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If you define "Internet traffic" to be HTTP traffic, then

> export http_proxy=”http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:port"
>
> export https_proxy="https://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:port"

NOTE: I don't have access to a RHEL6 machine to test, but it works on RHEL5.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for RHEL 6